# Безхатник, безхатченко, безхатько

Tags: синоніми

В ЗМІ, коли говорять про людиму без місця проживання, використовують такі слова- [безхатько](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=191611&page=145), [безхатченко](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=3768&page=145) або [безхатник](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=3765&page=145).

З визначень в СУМ-20 всі три слова є синонімами, але вони позначені, як розмовні.
Чи є не розмовний синонім до цих слів?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- [бездомний](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=3136&page=128)
- [безпритульний](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=3519&page=138) (в одному зі значень, бо може акцентуватись також відсутність догляду/опіки, а не місця постійного проживання)